# Change Initial Scale With Css

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

How can i change initial scale value with css? I don't want to use javascript.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@viewport`. But, it might not be supported in some browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport